# Authenticate Rest API with Apache Shiro

Tags: spring, rest, basic-authentication, shiro, digest-authentication

I have a Rest API backend (Rest based) which I want to secure now. I have looked into both Spring Security (for which I know implementation) and Apache Shiro. After learning that how shiro has a easy to use API, I want to implement it. However, there are no clear authorization tutorials to do this as I wanted to implement not just Basic Auth but Digest Authentication to have a more secured api. I have read that shiro has support for it. Also, I want to store my username and passwords in a databse and not in the ini file of shiro as shown in examples. Can anyone help me with this implementation? I have used Spring Rest for my apis.

Any suitable tutorial will help.

Comment: Why don't you go for Spring Security? Seems to be the obvious choice.

Comment: Yes, I went with Spring Security after doing a lot of digging. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

There are no digest examples yet in the Shiro [`samples`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples) dir.  It can be done, but you would need to dig it a bit (take a look how the [BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter.java) works)

As for storing your users in a Database (or anywhere for that matter) Shiro uses the term `realm` for this.  Here is an example [gist](https://gist.github.com/dominicfarr/9637357) that uses the [`JdbcRealm`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.html).

Comment: Thanks! I actually went with spring security after doing a lot of reading. It seemed like Shiro always maintains a session on server in all the related samples that I read. So, Spring Security all the way!!